# how to change content of variable with POST

Tags: php

For a filemanagement system, i use this variable in which is the folder that i use for a scandir:

`$dir = 'uploads/sfm/'.$UserID';`

Users can create their own directories inside their **$UserID** folder.

All files are outputted via a foreach.
To catch the path of a folder form "uploads", i use this:

```
$Dirname = dirname($dir);
$Basename = basename($dir);
```

Lets say i user has created a folder "test" in his own folder.
I catch that path with:

`$Dirname.'/'.$Basename.'/'.$file;`

when i echo this i get:

`uploads/sfm/5/test`

Now i want to change the $dir via a POST:
Below each folder which is outputted i created a form andwhen submit, the dir should change.

I do it now like this:

```
<form class="chdir" action="" method="post">
            <input class="hidden" name="<?php echo $Dirname.'/'.$Basename.'/'.$file; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="chdir" value="open dir" />
        </form>
```

And i try to change the dir like this:

```
$dir = 'uploads/sfm/'.$UserID;

if($_POST['chdir']) {
$NewDirectory = $_POST["$Dirname.'/'.$Basename.'/'.$file;"];
$dir = $NewDirectory;
//echo $dir;

}
```

i know the syntax is wrong but i hope you understand what i am trying to achieve: The **$dir** should contain now a the new value; so instead of this:
`$dir = 'uploads/sfm/'.$UserID';`

it should now contain this:

`$dir = 'uploads/sfm/'.$UserID.'/test';`

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no `class="hidden"` type in html you need to assign new directory to `value of hidden field` and add `name` into it as

```
<form class="chdir" action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="new_directory" value="<?php echo $Dirname.'/'.$Basename.'/'.$file; ?>"/>
            <input type="submit" name="chdir" value="open dir" />
        </form>
```

And get new directory as

```
$dir = 'uploads/sfm/'.$UserID;
if($_POST['chdir']) {
$NewDirectory = $_POST['new_directory'];// get your new_directory
$dir = $NewDirectory;
//echo $dir;

}
```

Comment: nice answer , i think it's better to not define new variables (Dirname and Pathname) and use the $dir variable directly ? `$dir . '/' . $file;`

Comment: yep absolutely directly use `$dir`